# How to make Drives visible to OS if they are connected to raid but raid is not configured

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, raid

So I have 4 drives that are "Unconfigured Good". They are not in any virtual drive. I want to present them without change them to `JBOD`. How to make my drives visible to OS keeping them as separate drives (not putting them into any kind of RAID)?

Comment: When you say `they are connected to raid`, you probably mean to a RAID controller, so how you can access them actually depends on that controller.  What is its exact model and have you already used them that way?

Comment: I am using "MegaRAID SAS 9361-4i" RAID controller. when i convert state to JBOD through megacli then it shows all the disks, but not all the controller has JBOD support. so i want to know, can we access physical drives in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Either your RAID controller supports JBOD(or can be flashed to a firmware that supports JBOD which is common with e.g. LSI-branded ones) or you need to resolve to a hack: Most RAID controllers allow you to do a single-disk RAID 0. In order to present the discs to the operating systems, you'll need to create a single disk RAID 0 for each drive in this case...

Comment: yes i can get control of hard disks after applyng RAID 0 to individual disks but the problem is that 'SIZE' and 'SECTOR' are showing less than the original. Means RAID 0 is taking some memory for it's configuration. But i want original means there should be no RAID at all?

Comment: No RAID at all = JBOD. If your controller doesn't support it you're out of luck.

Comment: Conditions are that the Disks are attached to RAID card but raid is not configured and JBOD is not supported then how to get handle of hard disks.

Comment: @AshishGahlaut:  We all apparently understand your concern but based on what you said, your controller doesn't support it.  You either get another controller or set them up as RAID.  Note that I can't see any benefit to avoiding RAID though.

Comment: But my question is that, after 'RAID DISMANTLING', naturally it should show all the drives without JBOD.

Answer (score 0):

On my HBA (LSI MegaRAID SAS 9266-8i) and with firmware version 3.460.115-6465 it was necessary to enable JBOD for the *controller*. Once that was done, all drives not part of a RAID automatically changed from "Unconfigured Good" to JBOD status.

Can't set -

```
root@olive:/home/hbarta# storcli /c0/e252/s2 set jbod
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Set Drive JBOD Failed.

Detailed Status :
===============

-------------------------------------------------
Drive       Status  ErrCd ErrMsg                 
-------------------------------------------------
/c0/e252/s2 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
-------------------------------------------------


root@olive:/home/hbarta#
```

Enable for controller -

```
root@olive:/home/hbarta# storcli /c0 set jbod=on
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = None


Controller Properties :
=====================

----------------
Ctrl_Prop Value 
----------------
JBOD      ON    
----------------


root@olive:/home/hbarta#
```

Still can't set but state is now JBOD -

```
root@olive:/home/hbarta# storcli /c0/e252/s2 set jbod
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Set Drive JBOD Failed.

Detailed Status :
===============

-------------------------------------------------
Drive       Status  ErrCd ErrMsg                 
-------------------------------------------------
/c0/e252/s2 Failure   255 Operation not allowed. 
-------------------------------------------------


root@olive:/home/hbarta# storcli /c0/e252/s2 show
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Show Drive Information Succeeded.


Drive Information :
=================

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG       Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                  Sp Type 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:2    18 JBOD  -  476.437 GB SATA SSD Y   N  512B Crucial_CT512MX100SSD1 U  -    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EID-Enclosure Device ID|Slt-Slot No.|DID-Device ID|DG-DriveGroup
DHS-Dedicated Hot Spare|UGood-Unconfigured Good|GHS-Global Hotspare
UBad-Unconfigured Bad|Onln-Online|Offln-Offline|Intf-Interface
Med-Media Type|SED-Self Encryptive Drive|PI-Protection Info
SeSz-Sector Size|Sp-Spun|U-Up|D-Down|T-Transition|F-Foreign
UGUnsp-Unsupported|UGShld-UnConfigured shielded|HSPShld-Hotspare shielded
CFShld-Configured shielded|Cpybck-CopyBack|CBShld-Copyback Shielded


root@olive:/home/hbarta#
```